# Inheritance Mapping and Many-To-One Relation

Tags: orm, doctrine, php-7, symfony3.x

I made an abstract Upload class with 4 different children.

The classes UploadCompanyPic, UploadCompanyLogo and UploadUserPic are one-to-one relations, but the UploadPostFile has to be Many-to-one (one post has many uploaded files), I want to use alle the functions that are in the abstract class, but I can't get the Many-to-one relation to work.
This is what I have since now:

```
<?php

        namespace AppBundle\Entity\Upload;

        use Doctrine\ORM\Event\LifecycleEventArgs;
        use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
        use AppBundle\Util\Registry;
        use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile;

        /**
         * Abstract Class Upload
         *
         * @package AppBundle\Entity\Upload
         *
         * @ORM\MappedSuperclass()
         * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\Upload\UploadRepository")
         * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
         * @ORM\Table(name="upload", indexes={
         *     @ORM\Index(name="idx_cat_id", columns={"category","foreign_id"})
         *      }
         * )
         * @ORM\InheritanceType("SINGLE_TABLE")
         * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="category", type="string")
         * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({"company-pic" = "UploadCompanyPic", "user-pic" = "UploadUserPic", "company-logo" = "UploadCompanyLogo", "post-file" = "UploadPostFile"})
         */
        abstract class Upload
        {
            /**
             * @ORM\Id
             * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
             * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", length=255, nullable=false)
             */
            protected $id;


            protected $foreignId;
       /**
some more code
         * @return mixed
         */
        public function getForeignId()
        {
            return $this->foreignId;
        }

        /**
         * @param mixed $foreignId
         */
        public function setForeignId($foreignId)
        {
            $this->foreignId = $foreignId;
        }
```

UploadCompanyPic:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity\Upload;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use AppBundle\Entity\Upload\Upload as Upload;

/**
 *
 * @ORM\Entity
 *
 */

class UploadCompanyPic extends Upload
{

    protected $category="company-pic";

    /**
     * this is the foreign id of the mapped entity
     * @ORM\Column(name="foreign_id", type="integer", length=255, nullable=false)
     */
    protected $foreignId;

}
```

(Upload CompanyLogo and UploadUserPic look the same)

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity\Upload;

use AppBundle\Entity\Blog\Post;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use AppBundle\Entity\Upload\Upload as Upload;

/**
 *
 * @ORM\Entity
 *
 */

class UploadPostFile extends Upload
{

    protected $category="post-file";


    /**
     * ManyFiles have one Post
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Blog\Post", inversedBy="files")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="foreign_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $foreignId;

    /**
     * @return ArrayCollection
     */
    public function getForeignId()
    {
        return $this->foreignId;
    }

    /**
     * @param Post $foreignId
     */
    public function setForeignId($foreignId)
    {
        $this->foreignId = $foreignId;
    }



}
```

Any suggestions for me? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One my colleagues found an answer:

```
/**
 * Abstract Class Upload
 *
 * @package AppBundle\Entity\Upload
 *
 * @ORM\MappedSuperclass()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\Upload\UploadRepository")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 * @ORM\Table(name="upload", indexes={
 *     @ORM\Index(name="idx_cat_id", columns={"category","foreign_id"})
 *      }
 * )
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("SINGLE_TABLE")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="category", type="string")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({"company-pic" = "UploadCompanyPic", "user-pic" = "UploadUserPic", "company-logo" = "UploadCompanyLogo", "post-file" = "UploadPostFile", "partner-logo" = "UploadPartnerLogo"})
 */
abstract class Upload
```

Comment: It is not supported to define inheritance information on a mapped superclass 'Upload'